# Why can't I unlink the copies in Blender 2.9?

Tags: modeling, linked-data, instances

I duplicated linked object multiple times (Alt+D) And now I can not get rid of the link for some copies. I tried: Apply - Make instances real, Make local - All (I tried all the parameters in Make local =D). Still, when I go to edit mode and try to move any vertices they are all affected. How do I get rid of the instancing for some copies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First way:

Press the button which indicates the number of users of a data block:

[image]

Second Way:

Object → Relations → Make Single User → Object & Data

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do is going into the header menu > *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*, you can do it with several objects, or, for a single object, go into the *Object Data* panel and click on the *make single user* button to unlink the mesh:

[image]